# Can jquery.find() select only direct children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

What argument should I provide to jQuery.find() to select the elements children and no other elements? I can't lead the selector with '>' and having '*' will select all descendants, not only direct children.

I am aware of jQuery.children(), but this is for a library so the user is able to provide their own selector, and I want to make sure they have some way of selecting just the direct children (without adding lots of my own logic).

***edit***

I want to use `jQuery.find()` to only find elements within the first level children of a parent element, not children of children.

Example:

```
<parent>
  <child-1>
    <child-2></child-2>
  </child-1>
  <child-1>
  </child-1>
</parent>
```

I want to only search through the elements `child-1` and not their children (i.e. child-2)

*EDIT:**

For more explanation, it is a Angular directive that goes on a table element. The directive needs to be able to find the table rows, but is meant to go on a wide variety of templates so it can have a selector for the rows. Sometimes the rows have no distinct features outside of being child divs to the original element; other times, the rows are grandchildren or even great-grandchildren.

Comment: Can you give an example usage? I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have a function that takes a jQuery and a selector and the function needs to be able to select the children in some cases, but select grandchildren in another case. Both those cases requires some sort of depth in the selector, but .find() doesn't really seem to work with specific depths (as there is no way to determine depth relative to original element).

Comment: Can you _show code_ of an example usage? I still don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: so you want to use `find` to only find within the first level children, not children of children?

Comment: There is also a method called `.children` in jQuery, might be of some use to you.

Comment: Uhm, use `.children(selector)` instead of `.find(selector)`?

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start your selector with `>` as you mentioned in your question. Try it:

```js
var s = ".classA",
    n = $('#wrapper').find('>'+s).length;

alert('Found '+ n +' direct children of #wrapper with the "'+ s +'" selector.'); // 3
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="classA"></div>     <!-- Selected -->
    <div class="classA">           <!-- Selected -->
        <div class="classA"></div> <!-- Ignored -->
    </div>
    <div class="classC">
        <div class="classA"></div> <!-- Ignored -->
    </div>
    <div class="classB">
        <div class="classB"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="classA"></div>     <!-- Selected -->
</div>
```

Or use `$.children()`, as you mentioned it in your question:

```js
var s = ".classA",
    n = $('#wrapper').children(s).length;

alert('Found '+ n +' direct children of #wrapper with the "'+ s +'" selector.'); // 3
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="classA"></div>     <!-- Selected -->
    <div class="classA">           <!-- Selected -->
        <div class="classA"></div> <!-- Ignored -->
    </div>
    <div class="classC">
        <div class="classA"></div> <!-- Ignored -->
    </div>
    <div class="classB">
        <div class="classB"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="classA"></div>     <!-- Selected -->
</div>
```

Comment: Leading `>` isn't standard CSS right? I Didn't even think to try it because of that and the .find API page not mentioning anything of the sort. Worked like a charm though.

Comment: You would not be able to use it on its own with a leading `>`, but here, it's being applied to the DOM element refered by jQuery, so it's not really "leading".

Answer (score 1):

*I am aware of jQuery.children(), but this is for a library so the user is able to provide their own selector*

But JQuery's `.children()` receives a selector as parameter:

> **.children( [selector ] )**
>   Description: Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

https://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 1):

Use **Immediate Child Elements** with `>` this is the code you need:

```
elemnt.find("> selector");
```

That should do the trick.